# Matlab-style function handles in c++

Tags: c++, matlab

In Matlab, one can restrict a function's inputs easily using function handles.  Suppose we have a Matlab function function `function z = f(x,y)`.  If I wanted to fix the value of `x` (say `x=0`) and consider a new function of `y` alone, I could use the simple function handle notation:

```
g = @(y) f(0,y)
```

I can then evaluate `g(y)` as if it were a regular function.  My question is, what is a good way to implement this behavior in C++?  Say I have a simple function object

```
struct f{
    double operator()(double x,double y){return x*y;}
};
```

Clearly I can evaluate `f(x,y)` for any pair of doubles `(x,y)`, but can I conveniently define a new function object `g(y)`, in terms of `f`, that fixes the value of `x`?

Comment: you are probably looking for [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: @tobi303 Looks pretty close, thanks for the hint!  If you post some sort of answer I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: sorry its quite some time ago I used it myself, I would have to start from the example given in the link and tbh i am not really in the mood. If you feel like you can answer your own question using what you find in the docs.